# Is one of these ways of adding a ListViewItem to a ListViewGroup wrong?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Here's some basic code to create a ListViewGroup, add it to the Groups collection of an existing ListView (listApplications), and then create a ListViewItem and add it to the ListviewGroup::

```
ListViewGroup AppCategory1 = new ListViewGroup("Cat1", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
AppCategory1.Tag = "ThereIsAnAppForThat";
listApplications.Groups.Add(AppCategory1);
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
//Now, which way of assigning a ListViewItem to a group is preferred? This way:
lvi.Group = AppCategory1;
//or this way:
AppCategory1.Items.Add(la);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN [ListViewGroup.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewgroup.items.aspx) documentation

> You can assign an item to a group by specifying the group in the ListViewItem constructor, by setting the ListViewItem.Group property, or by directly adding the item to the Items collection of a group.

So, there is no significant difference between these approaches.